How was the Llama 3.1 Tokenizer trained?
In the Llama 3.1 paper, they mention that combining 100k tokens from tiktoken with 28k additional non-English tokens improved the compression ratio for English. Is this improvement for English due to tiktoken being inherently better than the sentencepiece tokenizer used in Llama 2, or was there additional training involved for the tokenizer? If additional training occurred, how did the vocabulary size remain the same (100k for English)?


In the tokenizer training process, they broadened their sample set by including non-English languages (including some of the non-English languages in Roman script), which essentially improved compression rates. There are many algorithms used to train tokenizers, such as WordPiece, SentencePiece, Unigram, and Byte Pair Encoding (BPE) is one of them.
BPE is a compression algorithm used to train these LLM tokenizers. The basic idea of BPE is to iteratively merge the most frequent pair of consecutive bytes or characters in a text corpus until a predefined vocabulary size is reached. The resulting subword units can then be used to represent the original text in a more compact and efficient way.
The goal is to reduce the overall size of the text by breaking it into reusable parts that occur often. This allows the algorithm to represent words more efficiently, without needing to store every single character.
